# Create the dropdown title and the dropdown list menu side by side instead of up and down plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

How to create the dropdown title and the dropdown list menu side by side instead of up and down plotly?

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(html.H1("Testing",
                    className = 'text-center text-primary, mb-4 '
                    ,style={"textDecoration":"underline",'font-weight': 'bold'}),
            width=12
            ),
  
    ]),
html.Br(),
html.Br(),

dbc.Row([
   dbc.Col([
       html.H3('Product'
                ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
               ),
       
        
       dcc.Dropdown(id='product_dd', value= None,
                      options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                for x in product_cat],
                      
                      searchable = True, search_value='',
                      placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                      clearable=True
                      ),
       html.Br(),
       
       ], width=3, md=4),
])
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Did the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

- You should use two columns, one for the label and one for the dropdown menu.
- In order to put them in the same line, you should add `"flexWrap": "wrap"` to the `dbc.Row()` which contains the two columns.
- You should remove `html.Br()` between the label and the dropdown menu because it creates a new line.

Look at the full example below:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc




app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

items = [
    dbc.DropdownMenuItem("Item 1"),
    dbc.DropdownMenuItem("Item 2"),
    dbc.DropdownMenuItem("Item 3"),
]


app.layout = dbc.Container([
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(html.H1("Testing",
                    className = 'text-center text-primary, mb-4 '
                    ,style={"textDecoration":"underline",'font-weight': 'bold'})
            ),
  
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),

    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([   #<----- first column for label
               html.H3('Product',style={'font-size': '25px'})
               ]),
                   # remove from here the html.Br()
        dbc.Col([   #<----- second column for dropdown menu
                   dbc.DropdownMenu(items, label="Info", color="info")
                ])
    ],style={"flexWrap": "wrap", "width":"250px"}),
   
])


app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `className="hstack gap-2"` to make it side by side and set `minWidth` of dropdown. Please refer this below code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.H6('Template', style={'text-align': 'left'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='template',
                         placeholder="Please select template",
                         options=[{'label': 'ggplot2', 'value': 'ggplot2'},
                                  {'label': 'plotly_white', 'value': 'plotly_white'}],
                         value='ggplot2',
                                multi=True,
                                disabled=False,
                                clearable=True,
                                searchable=True,
                                style={'minWidth': '50%'})
        ], width={'size': 6, "offset": 0, 'order': 1},className="hstack gap-2"),
    ], className='p-2 align-items-center'),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Or you can add 2 columns, one for `html.H3` and one for `Dropdown` then set width of Col.